# How do I open files on server in a text editor from the command line?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-18.04

I'm sorry if this seems like beyond a beginner question, but I mean this seriously. I'm moving around my ubuntu server via the command line, trying to open a file called 'authorized_keys'. I tried: `root@ubuntu: open -a atom authorized_keys` only to learn this `open -a` command does not work in this ubuntu environment. I can download the files to my machine via sftp and open them, but is that the only way? Besides using nano/vim?

The tutorial I'm watching on deployment shows this guy using MobaXTerm, a windows product that allows both sftp and the command line to be present. So he is just clicking on the files on his server and they are opening. However, I am on mac, and only using the command line. Thanks for any help. I am also not sure If I tagged this question properly, feel free to move it.

Just read all of this and realized that I it would make sense if downloading and reuploading the file via sftp would be the only way.

Comment: That's why most people will end up learning enough of `nano` and `vim` to be somewhat productive in this kind of environment... Transferring files around locally and back for small edits gets onerous. Yeah some tools can help with that but it's hard to get great integration with the shell, work over sudo or additional ssh connections, etc. So at least that would be my personal recommendation, learn `vim` enough to help in these situations.

Comment: @filbranden awesome, thanks